# remove duplicate items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, mako

Current code:

```
mylist = [('x', 'Value1', 'Value2'), ('x', 'Value3', 'Value4')]

for item in mylist:
   item[0], item[1], item[2]
```

current for loop output:

```
x, Value1 : Value2, 
x, Value3 : Value4
```

wanted output:

```
x, "Value1 : Value2, Value3 : Value4"
```

(those are string colons which I render myself)

What is the best and correct way to do this?

(I'm rendering it in a .mako template)

Comment: What is it that you actually want to accomplish? You say that you want to remove duplicate items from a list, but I don't see any duplicates in the example you provide?

Comment: is it correct mixing colons and commas as separator or you want a comma separating all the values?

Comment: The 'x' values is what I meant.

Comment: @danielfranca Those colons are just string colons. That's what I render myself.

Comment: @Emre So, you want to group the items by the duplicates?

Comment: The duplicates can be any item on the tuple or only the first one?

Comment: It will be always the first one. @danielfranca

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129811/discussion-between-emre-and-danielfranca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionaries for that, adding the first element as the key.
Then add the last 2 items as an inner dictionary as key and value.

```
mylist = [('x', 'Value1', 'Value2'), ('x', 'Value3', 'Value4'), ('y', 'vvvv', 'mmmm')]

d = {}

for item in mylist:
   d.setdefault(item[0], "")
   d[item[0]] += ", " if len(d[item[0]]) else ""
   d[item[0]] += "{}: {}".format(item[1], item[2])

result = []
for k, v in d.items():
    t = [k]
    t.append(v)
    result.append(tuple(t))

print(result)
```

It already give you the output you desire:

> [('y', 'vvvv: mmmm'), ('x', 'Value1: Value2, Value3: Value4')]

Comment: Well I can't get to seem it work(at the frontend). How can I pass this in a list so I can access the 'x' with [0] and 'Value1': 'Value2', 'Value3': 'Value4' with [1]?

Comment: @Emre Just updated the code with the format you want, then you can access it as a list. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Daniel franca guided me through personal chat and we finally got it working. He's a really chill and calm guy. He deserves more than just a +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this by using a dictionary as follows

```
mylist = [('x', 'Value1', 'Value2'), ('x', 'Value3', 'Value4')]

d = {}

for item in mylist:
    x = item[0]
    if x in d:
        d[x].append((item[1], item[2]))
    else:
        d[x] = [(item[1], item[2])]

 for key in d:
    print key, d[key]
```

The dictionary `d` enables us to club together all duplicate occurrences of `item[0]` and add the tuple `(item[1], item[2])` to a list associated with each unique value of `item[0]`

I trust that you can adjust the code to obtain the output format you desire

Comment: I try to pass this as a list, so that I can loop through the list and get the output I wanted(example in question. But I can't seem to get it work that way.

Answer (score 0):

how about this code?

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [('x', 'Value1', 'Value2'), ('x', 'Value3', 'Value4'), ('x2', 'value5', 'value6')]
result = defaultdict(list)
for item1, item2, item3 in mylist:
    result[item1].append({item2:item3})

print(result)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'x': [{'Value1': 'Value2'}, {'Value3': 'Value4'}], 'x2': [{'value5': 'value6'}]})
```

Comment: current output: x {'Value1': 'Value2'} {'Value3': 'Value4'}. Which isn't iterable. I want it to be iterable so I can loop through it and get the example in the question.

Comment: I edit the code, you can access elements of output dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the collections.defaultdict!

```
import collections
mylist = [('x', 'Value1', 'Value2'), ('x', 'Value3', 'Value4')]
answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
for group in mylist:
    key = group[0]
    rest = group[1:]
    values = [x for x in rest]
    answer[key] += values

# Output
# In [5]: answer
# Out[5]: defaultdict(list, {'x': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']})
```